# Why is there no $H_1H_1\bar{e}^c$ term in the most general renormalisable superpotential?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, standard-model, supersymmetry, mssm

I am these [notes](http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/%7Eajd268/Notes/Supersymmetry.pdf) by Jeff Asaf Dror on Supersymmetry. In the section on the MSSM, it is stated that the most general renormalisable superpotential is given by

$$W=y_1QH_2\bar{u}^c+y_2QH_1\bar{d}^c+y_3LH_1\bar{e}^c+\mu H_1H_2 + W_{BL} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(9.4)$$
where
$$W_{BL}=\lambda_1LL\bar{e}^c+\lambda_2 LQ\bar{d}^c+\lambda_3 \bar{u}^c\bar{d}^c\bar{d}^c+\mu'LH_2\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(9.5)$$
includes the terms with break baryon or lepton number.

However, I don't understand why the term

$$H_1H_1\bar{e}^c$$
isn't included in $W_{BL}$? It respects the $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ symmetry group of the Standard Model, and dimensionally, one would expect this term to be renormalisable as the product of three chiral superfields. So why is it not included? Other sources (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-parity)) also explicitly mention the four terms given in $W_{BL}$, but not $H_1H_1\bar{e}^c$.